# Postgres: How do you cleanup unsused tablespace files

Tags: postgresql, tablespace

I have a build process that bootstraps a DB the first time it is run.  After that, the DB is exported with pg_dump and then re-imported for subsequent builds until a "force bootstrap" build is performed.  The problem is that the database name is created and defined by the build and then dropped at the beginning/end of the build to force initialisation.  There are six table spaces, but each build is creating objects that end up in /var/lib/pgsql/tablespaces, that eventually fills up the file system.  I can't drop a table space, because there might be another concurrent build running.

Isn't there a vacuum job or something to delete the files in /var/lib/pgsql/tablespaces when they are no longer being referenced?

I am guessing that the DB export creates new tablespace objects each time it is imported, which is why it grows infinitely.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have to drop ALL databases that are currently referencing any tablespace.  Then and only then, does postgres perform cleanup and drops the tablespaces.  This seems utterly insane.  But from a build node point of view, I can configure a build job to run cleanup of all databases during quiet periods.

Comment: Actually, that kind of makes sense. Tablespaces aren't "under" a database; they're "under" a server.  A database that still references a tablespace might be about to store something *in* the tablespace.